# Simple MergeSort Java

Tags: java, eclipse, mergesort

I have a class lab due tomorrow and am absolutely stumped.  The requirement is simply: Make a mergeSort Algorithm that sorts the given ArrayList using comparables.  "a" will have the final sorted list. It is currently throwing the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at Sorts.merge(Sorts.java:142)
at Sorts.mergesort(Sorts.java:161)
at Sorts.mergesort(Sorts.java:160)
at Sorts.mergesort(Sorts.java:159)
at SortStep.sortMenu(SortStep.java:65)
at SortStep.main(SortStep.java:168)
```

Anything helps! Thanks! (I know the line numbers don't help you guys. Sorry!)

```
/**
 * Takes in entire vector, but will merge the following sections together:
 * Left sublist from a[first]..a[mid], right sublist from a[mid+1]..a[last].
 * Precondition: each sublist is already in ascending order
 *
 * @param a
 *            reference to an array of integers to be sorted
 * @param first
 *            starting index of range of values to be sorted
 * @param mid
 *            midpoint index of range of values to be sorted
 * @param last
 *            last index of range of values to be sorted
 */
private void merge(ArrayList<Comparable> a, int first, int mid, int last) {
    ArrayList<Comparable> temp = new ArrayList<Comparable>();

    while (first <= mid && mid <= last) {
        if (a.get(first).compareTo(a.get(mid)) > 0) {
            temp.add(a.get(first));
            first++;
        } else {
            temp.add(a.get(mid));
            mid++;
        }
    }

    while (first < mid) {
        temp.add(a.get(first));
        first++;
    }

    while (mid <= last) {
        temp.add(a.get(mid));
        mid++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= last; i++)
        a.set(i, temp.get(i));
}

/**
 * Recursive mergesort of an array of integers
 *
 * @param a
 *            reference to an array of integers to be sorted
 * @param first
 *            starting index of range of values to be sorted
 * @param last
 *            ending index of range of values to be sorted
 */
public void mergesort(ArrayList<Comparable> a, int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        mergesort(a, first, mid);
        mergesort(a, mid + 1, last);
        merge(a, first, last, mid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error? You're accessing an element of the array list that doesn't exist, meaning your index math is off somewhere.

Comment: One typo here `merge(a, first, last, mid);` which clearly should be `merge(a, first, mid, last);`

Answer (score 1):

- The method `merge` expect arguments as `first, mid, last`, but what is passed is `first, last, mid`.
- `mid` is moving ahead, so extra elements may be stored in `temp`.
- The last loop of `merge` is wrong and it should start from what was in `first` when the method is called, not `0`.
- The range of each section is wrong.

corrected code:

```
private void merge(ArrayList<Comparable> a, int first, int mid, int last) {
    ArrayList<Comparable> temp = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
    mid++;

    int firstFirst = first;
    int firstEnd = mid;
    while (first < firstEnd && mid <= last) {
        if (a.get(first).compareTo(a.get(mid)) > 0) {
            temp.add(a.get(first));
            first++;
        } else {
            temp.add(a.get(mid));
            mid++;
        }
    }

    while (first < firstEnd) {
        temp.add(a.get(first));
        first++;
    }

    while (mid <= last) {
        temp.add(a.get(mid));
        mid++;
    }

    for (int i = firstFirst; i <= last; i++)
        a.set(i, temp.get(i - firstFirst));
}

public void mergesort(ArrayList<Comparable> a, int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        mergesort(a, first, mid);
        mergesort(a, mid + 1, last);
        merge(a, first, mid, last);
    }
}
```